# Not able to run Maven project in Eclipse

Tags: maven, selenium

I am trying to run my Maven project from eclipse but after giving Maven Test from eclipse I am getting below messages with no errors but the project is not launching and it keeps on searching for it.
Though the project is working fine when running it through TestNG.xml.
Please find below image for the processing messages.

Comment: Not able to attach image of error but site has generated below link.
http://i.stack.imgur.com/J5cXw.png

Comment: In general, try upgrading to a more recent version of the problematic plugin. In this case: most recent version of maven-surefire-plugin is 2.19.1

Comment: Can you share an image of the directory structure of the the project?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the [link](http://howtodoinjava.com/testng/how-to-execute-testng-tests-with-maven-build/) for all the configurations required for the migration to maven. But bet sure with the maven path in your eclipse and what mvn goal your trying to it. It is better to use "test" or "verify".